# Calculating and displaying a ConvexHull

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, convex-hull

I'm trying to calculate and show a convex hull for some random points in python.

This is my current code:

```py
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

points = np.random.rand(25,2)   

hull = ConvexHull(points)

plt.plot(points[:,0], points[:,1], 'o',color='c')

for simplex in hull.simplices:
    plt.plot(points[simplex, 0], points[simplex, 1], 'r')

plt.plot(points[hull.vertices,0], points[hull.vertices,1], 'r', lw=-1)
plt.plot(points[hull.vertices[0],0], points[hull.vertices[0],1], 'r-')
plt.show()
```

My questions:

- How can I change the X,Y labels and points limit between 0 to 9? For example (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
- How can I mark the points on the convex hull with a circle?
  [As in example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2J2n.jpg)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replacing `np.rand()` with `randint(0, 10)` will generate the coordinates as integers from `0,1,...` to `9`.

Using '.' as marker will result in smaller markers for the given points.

Using 'o' as marker, setting a markeredgecolor and setting the main color to 'none' will result in a circular marker, which can be used for the points on the hull. The size of the marker can be adapted via `markersize=`.

`fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=..., nrows=...)` is a handy way to create multiple subplots.

Here is some code for a minimal example:

```py
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

points = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(15, 2))  # Random points in 2-D

hull = ConvexHull(points)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(10, 3))

for ax in (ax1, ax2):
    ax.plot(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], '.', color='k')
    if ax == ax1:
        ax.set_title('Given points')
    else:
        ax.set_title('Convex hull')
        for simplex in hull.simplices:
            ax.plot(points[simplex, 0], points[simplex, 1], 'c')
        ax.plot(points[hull.vertices, 0], points[hull.vertices, 1], 'o', mec='r', color='none', lw=1, markersize=10)
    ax.set_xticks(range(10))
    ax.set_yticks(range(10))
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

PS: To show the plots in separate windows:

```py
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

points = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(15, 2))  # Random points in 2-D
hull = ConvexHull(points)
for plot_id in (1, 2):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=1, figsize=(5, 3))
    ax.plot(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], '.', color='k')
    if plot_id == 1:
        ax.set_title('Given points')
    else:
        ax.set_title('Convex hull')
        for simplex in hull.simplices:
            ax.plot(points[simplex, 0], points[simplex, 1], 'c')
        ax.plot(points[hull.vertices, 0], points[hull.vertices, 1], 'o', mec='r', color='none', lw=1, markersize=10)
    ax.set_xticks(range(10))
    ax.set_yticks(range(10))
    plt.show()
```

Comment: I have another a little question. How can i get  another output, in only shows points?

Comment: One another display but had to shows only points . Like this ; 
--> First display shows only points 
--> Second display calculate convex hull and shows