# How to draw pentagonl with opencv in Python

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I'm trying to draw a convex hull on random points but I have to do this using with opencv - *not* convexhull command or `scpiy` or `hull` lib)

- First step, I create random points between 14 - 20 numbers.
- However, I need something like this.

  How can I save the plt.show() resultant graphic and draw convex hull like that?

Here's my code:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
points = []
points_limit = 12+random.randint(0, 7)
print(points_limit)

for x in range(points_limit):
    points.append([random.randint(0, 9),random.randint(0, 9)])

print(points)

for point in points:
   plt.scatter(point[0],point[1], color='k', s=100)

print(points)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Why don't you draw the convex hull as in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62376042/calculating-and-displaying-a-convex-hull)? Opencv is meant for computer vision.

Comment: @JohanC first of all thank you for answer about previous question. But i have to proof in to my  dissertation at school about  this question with convex hull and with opencv.

Comment: So, did you try openCv's [`cv.convexHull`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=convexhull#convexhull)? What did or didn't work as expected? How did you try to solve these problems?

Comment: @JohanC first step  , i have to save this graphic as a image and use with cv2.imread . Then " points " had a random points coordinates. I think , i can draw convex hull with between two points slope  or step by step draw with outside points coordinates. If i'm wrong please tell me the correct .

Comment: @JohanC Your previous answer is working really great by the way.